# Django many-to-many inline model admin selects waaay too many rows from rel

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to make a `n-to-n` rel work the way that it shows the corresponding relationship in the admin page for each of the two models in this rel. Out of the box only the model that has the relationship defined on it gets the form on its admin page. So i have followed the official documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects
As you should see(below in my code) i have basically added exactly what it says.
Now my problem is that i have about 350k rows in this mapping table, but if i select in my database one `bar` only has 80 `foos`, and the reverse selection maybe 140. Now it seems like it selects 147k rows(!), so it seems like it somehow selects about half of my entire join table even though i am just clicking on a specific `foo`. So somehow it seems like it isn't doing just a simple join between the two models with ids, when i look in my sql log the SQL it generates is just selecting things from one table at a time, which is weird because the join can be done in 1 line.

So i have a Django app that has the following models:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    bars = models.ManyToManyField(Bar, related_name='foos')
```

The `bars` don't have a relation back to the `foos` which is how n-to-n works.

Now i wanted to show on the `/admin/bars/<id>` all of the `foos` it has in its rel, and on the `/admin/bars/<id>` i wanted to show all of the `bars` that it has. Automatically the `foos` endpoint works out of the box because it is the model i defined the `n-to-n` rel on, but on the `bars` it requires a bit more work. 
So i followed the official tutorial to make a Inline model in the `admin.py` and make the two admin models share this Inline:

```
class FooBarInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Foo.bars.through
    extra = 1
```

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #... list_display, list_filter etc.
    inlines = (FooBarInline, )
    exclude = ('bars', )
```

```
class BarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #... list_display, list_filter etc.
    inlines = (FooBarInline, )
```

Can anyone figure out why it is behaving like this? i don't have any circular definitions or anything, very simple `n-to-n` rel tbh. Or maybe give me some pointers as how to debug the SQL being generated by a Inline model? then i could maybe find out on my own.

Thank you so much!